# Broadcast Action: ACTION_CAMERA_BUTTTON

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver

Is there any way after this action has been broadcast via a receiver to determine that the action has finished? i.e the user has exit camera mode and is doing something else?

Answer (score 1):

You can register a [broadcast receiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html) to receive this intent.

Note however that this intent will be broadcasted every time the user pushes the camera button, and is thus not directly related to any specific "action" (e.g. taking a photo).

```
BroadcastReceiver myReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {     
    @Override     
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {         
        // do whatever you want to do     
    } 
};

registerReceiver(myReceiver, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_CAMERA_BUTTON)); 
unregisterReceiver(myReceiver);
```

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I am doing. My question is though, if there's anyway I can receive,  an intent or something else, that will tell me that the user has exit camera mode.

Comment: @kkudi you find a manual on how to take photos in the Android docs http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html - no broadcasting involved. If taking photos is not your goal, please clarify your question.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way after this action has been broadcast via a receiver to determine that the action has finished?

No. For starters, there may be no "action" to "finish", and there is no definition of "action".

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand what you're trying to say.By action I am referring to the fact that the camera button was pressed. Somehow that "action" will "finish". I was asking if there was anyway I could detect that.

Comment: @kkudi: "By action I am referring to the fact that the camera button was pressed." -- Um, OK. "Somehow that "action" will "finish"." -- what do you think it means to "finish" a button press?